# Mobile Form Fields - Losing Focus

Tags: iphone, html, cordova, mobile, input

I'm developing a mobile/web application. When I view form fields in a mobile browser, like iPhone's safari or even the chrome mobile app, I can't lose focus on form fields unless I press another form element or "Done" on the keyboard..

I've even completely stripped my code down to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
             <input type="text"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and I still can't lose focus (in mobile browsers) of the text field by pressing elsewhere!

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
  var nodeName = evt.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  if (nodeName !== "input" && nodeName !== "textarea" && nodeName !== "select") {
    document.activeElement.blur();
  }
});
```

Comment: ah genius! I removed the".body", as this caused an error, however now works fine, thanks!

Comment: True, document.addEventListener is better. That event listener can also be added when input is focused and removed after it's blurred. This would prevent any conflicts with other event listeners.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found this hack works

```
document.body.firstElementChild.tabIndex = 1
```

This makes the first element in the body focusable thus when you click "outside" the input it loses focus. At the same time you don't see any visual glitches on that focused element because there is not style defined (unless your first body child element is something other than div)